# git clone without replacing file tree

Tags: git, github

I have a gitignore that only sends two subdirectories to github.

my gitignore

```
/*
!/conf
/conf/*
!/conf/jingle_profiles
!/conf/dialplan
```

this uploads the two subdirectories (dialplan,jingle_profiles) to github.

I want to clone those subdirectories into the root file tree (/usr/local/freeswitch) and have them keep those two subdirectories synced without deleting everything else.

edit:

the error I get when I:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/dgmcguire/freeswitch.git
```

is

```
fatal: destination path 'freeswitch' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Comment: Have you tried it? git shouldn't delete ignored files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clone` requires an empty directory, but subsequent pulls won't do anything to ignored files.

So, simply create an empty subdirectory inside `/usr/local/freeswitch`, do your `git clone` inside that subdirectory and afterwards, move the contents of this subdirectory to `/usr/local/freeswitch`.

Should be something like this:

```
mkdir /usr/local/freeswitch/git_tmp
cd /usr/local/freeswitch/git_tmp
git clone https://github.com/dgmcguire/freeswitch.git
mv /usr/local/freeswitch/git_tmp/* /usr/local/freeswitch/
rm -r -d /usr/local/freeswitch/git_tmp
```

I am no linux guy, so there might be some errors in the commands used - the intent however should be clear.

Answer (score -1):

`.gitignore` is not specifically related github or uploading stuff. It controls which files git considers when checking for untracked files.

I recommend you learn a bit more about how git works. A very, very good resource is ProGit - [here's](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) where it discusses .gitignore, but you should really read the first few chapters.